# How to set formula with condition query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

| invoice | ProdId | Price | amount | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10 | 2 | 20.2 |
| 1 | 2 | 20 | 1 | 20.2 |
| 1 | 3 | 10 | 2 | 20.2 |
| 2 | 1 | 10 | 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 2 | 20 | 2 | 20 |

How to query if an invoice has only `prodID = 1` or 2 then `price * Amount` else `price * amount + 1%`.

Comment: 10% would be 22, 20.2 is 1%

Comment: What if an invoice *only* has ProdId 1? Which branch should that go to?

Comment: Here is a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/y44psU9j) for the first two answers below, with an extra invoice to show the difference - requiring both 1 & 2 vs allowing any combination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the invoice just needs to have either ProdId of `1` or `2` or both but nothing else then you can use

```
select *, 
        result1 = price * amount * max(iif(ProdId not in (1,2), 1.01, 1)) over (partition by invoice)
from YourTable;
```

If the invoice needs exactly both ProdId of `1` or `2` to be present a SQL Server 2022 method might be

```
select *,
         result2 = price * amount * least(max(iif(ProdId = 1, 1.01, 1)) over W, max(iif(ProdId = 2, 1.01, 1)) over W)
from YourTable
WINDOW W AS ( PARTITION BY invoice)
```

Comment: Hi Smith,
i meant if the invoice has only ProdIDs (Which ID 1 or 2 or both of them) then do not add 1%, but if the invoce include orthers ID even this invoce has prodID 1,2 then add 1%

Comment: @HuyHoangNguyen - so the first method in my answer should be the one you need. I replaced `1.1` with `1.01` following the clarification to the question.

Comment: Thanks Smith, can you please help me if there is 1 more condition to the query is that PaymentMethod = 'card' or 'cash', if card then your query, if 'cash' then  no add 1%, so there is 1 more column   'PaymentMethod '

Comment: Presumably you need to adjust the `iif` clause - e.g. instead of `iif(ProdId not in (1,2), 1.01, 1)` you want something like  `iif(PaymentMethod = 'card' and ProdId not in (1,2), 1.01, 1)`

Comment: here is my query:

Comment: iif (PaymentMethod = 'Cash',price * amount ,price  * amount * max(iif(ProdId not in (398,399), 1.01, 1)) over (partition by invoice)) result
It works, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use a conditional expression to determine the multiplier and *exists* to check the criteria:

```
select *, 
  result = price * amount * 
    case when exists (
      select * from t t2 
      where t2.invoice = t.invoice 
      having Min(prodid) = 1 and Max(prodid) = 2
    ) then 1 else 1.1 end
from t;
```